# How do we pass dynamic variable into JavaScript dictionary

Tags: javascript, json

i have mentioned bellow code i want that when user put  amount in input field i want this amount to be add in  java script amount key

**form**

```
  <form id="payment-form">
      <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount">
  </form>
```

**script**

```
 <script>
 SpreedlyExpress.init("C7cRfNJGODKh4Iu5Ox3PToKjniY", {
 "amount": "$9.83",
 "company_name": "AA crypto hedge"
 });
 </script>
```

actually i want to change  amount dynamicaly in $9.00 when user enter amount in input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd attach a submit handler to the form and call your function inside, passing a variable for the amount:

```html
<form id="payment-form" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount">
</form>

<script>
const amount = document.getElementById("amount");

const mockSpreedlyExpress = {
  init: (str, obj) => console.log(str, JSON.stringify(obj))
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!amount.value) return;
  mockSpreedlyExpress.init("C7cRfNJGODKh4Iu5Ox3PToKjniY", {
    amount: amount.value,
    company_name: "AA crypto hedge"
  });
  amount.value = "";
}
 
</script>
```